# Ruby Array of hashes to a Hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array that looks something like this

```
array = [{ a: 123, b: 'foo', c: 'bar' }, { a: 456, b: 'baz', c: 'qux' }]
```

I would like to convert this to a hash whose keys are the values of `:a` in the hashes in `array`, and whose values consist of hashes with `:b` and `:c`.

```
{ 123 => { b: 'foo', c: 'bar' }, 456 => { b: 'baz', c: 'qux' } }
```

Is this doable using ruby?

Comment: sure it is, what have you already tried?

Comment: Agreed, show what have you already tried. Meanwhile take a look at `each_with_object` and `reject` methods from `Enumerable`module (https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array.each_with_object({}){|e, h| e = e.dup; h[e.delete(:a)] = e}
# => {123=>{:b=>"foo", :c=>"bar"}, 456=>{:b=>"baz", :c=>"qux"}}
```

If you don't care about side effects:

```
array.each_with_object({}){|e, h| h[e.delete(:a)] = e}
# => {123=>{:b=>"foo", :c=>"bar"}, 456=>{:b=>"baz", :c=>"qux"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what problem you're trying to solve. This is what I come out with:

```
def group_by_key(array, key)
  array.map { |x| [x.delete(key), x] }.to_h
end
```

It works good on your example:

```
array = [{ a: 123, b: 'foo', c: 'bar' }, { a: 456, b: 'baz', c: 'qux' }]
group_by_key(array, :a)
#=> {123=>{:b=>"foo", :c=>"bar"}, 456=>{:b=>"baz", :c=>"qux"}}
```

Comment: Note that `delete` will mutate the hashes within `array`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all elements of `array` (hashes) have a key `:a` and that `array` cannot be mutated, use [Hash#reject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-reject):

```
array.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h[g[:a]] = g.reject { |k,_| k == :a } }
  #=> {123=>{:b=>"foo", :c=>"bar"}, 456=>{:b=>"baz", :c=>"qux"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Hash#select](https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/select) method.

```
array.map { |v| [v.fetch(:a), v.select { |k,_| k != :a }] }.to_h
```

Exact `:a, :b & :c`

```
array.map { |v| [v.fetch(:a), v.select { |k,_| [:b, :c].include? k }] }.to_h
```

Output

```
{123=>{:b=>"foo", :c=>"bar"}, 456=>{:b=>"baz", :c=>"qux"}}
```